# what if a person steals and repents but dies before paying the stolen amount to rightful owner?

Tags: sin, punishment

So suppose there is a person who stole but then he returns to Allah and repents sincerely , he is young and doesn't earn on his own nor he has enough money. So he makes intention to pay back that amount as soon as he is able to in future (after completing studies and getting a job), but he dies before that time period. Is he forgiven? or he will be punished?

Comment: He should have made a bequest to his heirs to discharge this duty. Whether or not he is forgiven depends on the person who was wronged. If the victim forgave him then its alright, otherwise the victim can claim a part of the good deeds of the thief or if the thief has no good deeds then the victim can give his own bad deeds to the thief.